# Vue warn : Failed to resolve component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I hope you are all well. I'm currently having some issues with using a component that is inside a parent component. I tried a few things but without success...
The component **ModalBoxActionArticle** doesn't want to show and I have the following error message :

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: ModalBoxActionArticle    at
>     at <Home
> onVnodeUnmounted=fn ref=Ref< undefined > >    at
>     at

Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Find below the **vue View** that is at the root of these components:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
      <ImageArticle class="home__component"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ImageArticle from "../components/imageArticle"

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    ImageArticle,
  }
}
</script>
```

Find below the **ImageArticle** component (I removed the style)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <article class="postWithImage">
            <ModalBoxActionArticle/>
            <div class="postWithImage__1div">
                <picture class="postWithImage__pictureProfile">
                    <img class="postWithImage__imgProfile" src="../assets/EugenieProfile.jpeg" alt="photo de profile de la personne qui a publié l'image">
                </picture>
                .... here I removed some html to make it more readable ....

        </article>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModalBoxActionArticle from '../components/modalBoxActionArticle'

export default {
    name: 'ImageArticle',
    component : {
        ModalBoxActionArticle
    },
    setup() {
        console.log('%c loading ImageArticle component', 'color:green');
        return {};
    },
}
</script>
```

Last but not least find below, the component **ModalBoxActionArticle** that is inside the **ImageArticle** component

```
<template>
    <div class="modal">
        <button class="modal__btt modal__btt--alert">Signaler</button>
        <button class="modal__btt">Partager</button>
        <button class="modal__btt">Modifier</button>
        <button class="modal__btt modal__btt--alert">Supprimer</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ModalBoxActionArticle",
    setup() {
        console.log('%cloading ModalBoxActionArticle newest component', 'color:red');
        return {};
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `ImageArticle.vue` you have defined

```
component : {
   ModalBoxActionArticle
},
```

This must be like (the letter `s` must be at the end of the word `component`):

```
components : {
   ModalBoxActionArticle
},
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I feel so very ashamed of my mistake... Such a simple one...

Comment: Apropos typos: make sure the html element you use actually exists in the spec. Not-so-random example: <quote> doesn't exist; <blockquote> does.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occured because there was a **typo** in my **component** while **importing**!

"***Vue***" was actually following component name:

```
import PropsPassingVue from './components/PropsPassing.vue';
```

It should be:

```
import PropsPassing from './components/PropsPassing.vue';
```

So make sure your component is spelled right!